# Powershell convertfrom-json | convertto-csv

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a JSON data structured as following (there may be some mistakes here, the data I'm using is fine):

```
[{
"id": 12345,
"itemName": "some string",
"sellerId": 123,
"seller": "",
"categoryId": ,
"categoryPath": [
  {
   //more data
  },
  {
   //more data
  }
]}, 
{"id": 12346,
"itemName": "some other string",
"sellerId": 234,
"seller": "",
"categoryId": ,
"categoryPath": [
  {
   //more data
  },
  {
   //more data
  }
]
}]
```

I would like to convert it to csv so that the selected property names become csv headers and their value (depth 1 only) become data.
e.g

```
id,itemName,sellerId
12345,"some string",123
12346,"some other string",234
```

I've tried using hundreds of variations of

```
cat file.json | convertfrom-json | convertto-csv
```

but none have worked. All I get is csv data with objects names/types and I can't figure out how to make it use only selected properties of each object from json data.

Comment: Not a huge deal but your input data would not match your sample output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've made the sample output match the input data.

Comment: I could not do it in one line. Does this work for you? `$converted = Get-Content file.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json;$converted | Select id,itemName,sellerId | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation`. Needed to save the results to a variable first for some reason that I don't know yet. Works aafter that .

Comment: I'm speechless. It works and I even figured out how to make oneliner out of it. It seems that putting parentheses around iwr and convertfrom-json solves the problem. I think it may be connected to the way Powershell handles objects. Anyway, below Is the command that worked. 
`(iwr "url" | convertfrom-json) | select id, itemname | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Yeah... I know what my issue was.. Making an answer now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short you need to do something like this:

```
(Get-Content file.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select id,itemName,sellerId | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

The first problem was that `Get-Content` was passing individual lines to  `ConvertFrom-Json` which is not what it wants. Using the `-Raw` switch passes it in its entirety.

The `(Get-Content file.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json)` needs to be in parentheses as that allows us to continue with the pipe. The properties are not accessible without doing this. It looks like it is trying to pass the entire object instead of its individual parts down the pipe.

`-NoTypeInformation` removes lines like this

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

Comment: Thanks...it was really helpful.

Comment: At last i have added to export into csv.                                                                                                             (Get-Content file.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select id,itemName,sellerId | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content file.csv